# Alternative to 'publish' in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am working on an app with configurable files. When i publish i notice 1) I get an installer which i dont think i can opt out of 2) I dont know where the install path is and if i change the config files the application will not install (maybe not run either if i edit them in the right place?)

So what alternatives do i have? I would like some event i can run which builds in release mode then copies the release.exe and any config/media file and move it to path/deploy/prj/ so i can zip it or share it instead of a path in my sensitive path/src area (bonus is i can share deploy if i want all projects to be available (and no source))

Using visual studio 2010

-edit- also i need some data in src/relatedprj/bin/*, to be copied into the root
-edit2- is there an easy way to run bat files in visual studio 2010? maybe i should use that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a deployment project (add one to your solution) and see if that covers what you need.